# 2 dhcp servers on same network

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I have a Bell home router that doesn’t support port forward ranges , just single ports. It does have DMZ though so....

I was thinking of having my Ubuntu 14 headless run a DHCP service and then doing my thing and forward the ports that way. ( Have the Bell router DMZ to the IP of the Ubuntu Server as it already has 2 NICs.)

Then the devices that I need to use port forward ranges I will give static IPs pointing to the Ubuntu DHCP

Other devices like my phone , tablets etc I don't care what DHCP server they get there info from.

*Or... Is this a bad idea?*

Comment: What you suggest is feasible, however I would turn off DHCP on the router if you intend to use the Ubuntu server to provide DHCP.

Answer (score 2):

Having 2 DHCP servers on the same network is definitely **not** a good idea, so I would do **one of the 3 options** below:

1. Turn the DHCP service off on the Bell and add a wireless card (capable of playing AP) to the server and have it as the DHCP server
2. DMZ the server, but don't give it DHCP capabilites and run everything that needs to be connected to the server to a cheap switch that is connected to the server and assign the IPs manually and forward everything.
3. DMZ the server, fixed IP on both NICs and subnet the network.  E.g. 192.168.1.0/24on the Bell, 192.168.2.0/24 on the switch. (the you have 2 DHCP servers on 2 networks)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)